# Why JWT token is not working after deploying to firebase?

Tags: firebase, deployment, jwt, vercel

```
const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    }
    else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    }
    

}


export const loginUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/login',userData)
    .then(res => {
        const {token} = res.data;
        // set token to local storage
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
        //set token to Auth header;

        setAuthToken(token);
        //Decode token to get user data

        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

        dispatch( setCurrentUser(decoded) );


    })
    .catch(err => dispatch ({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
    }))
    
}
```

Everything is fine when I run my app locally but after deploying to firebase,jwt token is set to "undefined" in the local storage. "loginUser" function is called after clicking the login button.
Please suggest me the possible solutins.

Note: There is no problem with environment variable because I have tried without using environment variable.

Comment: A little bit of progress I guess. At least now I know why it's happening!
I console-logged the response . After deploying  res.data isn't an object but locally res.data is an object. Weird!!